# Can I insert into temp table from SP without declaring table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is my code:

```
alter procedure test1 as
select DeptID,DeptName from Department
go

alter procedure test2 as
--Create Table #tab (DeptID INT, DeptName VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO #tab
exec test1
select * from #tab
drop table #tab
go

exec test2
```

I am getting an error like "Invalid object name #tab"

If I add at the begining `Create Table #tab (DeptID INT, DeptName VARCHAR(255))` then I do not get any error.

What is wrong in my code? Can I populate a temp table from the results of a stored procedure without declaring the temp table and its column definitions?

Comment: Do you want to populate a temp table with the results of a Stored Procedure without having to first create the table definition? Basically, a dynamically created temp table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When loading a temp table from a stored procedure, then you have to CREATE the table first.

There is no straightforward equivalent of

```
SELECT * INTO #temptable FROM AnotherTable
```

The non-straightforward version (read all about the bad stuff on ["How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures"](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY). And [simpler](http://blogs.clarience.com/davide/?p=6)) would be

```
SELECT * INTO #temptable FROM OPENQUERY(Loopback, 'exec test1')
```

Comment: what is loop back here any way i solved the problem....thanks.alter procedure test1 as 
select DeptID,DeptName from Department
go

alter procedure test2 as 
SELECT *
INTO #tab
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'server=192.168.1.12\bbareman;trusted_connection=yes',
'set fmtonly off exec MyTest.dbo.test1')
select * from #tab
drop table #tab
go

Answer (score 1):

It's because the Local Temporary table `#tab` which you are expecting does not existing in the session.

So the table creation should not be commented line.

```
Create Table #tab (DeptID INT, DeptName VARCHAR(255))
```

Moreover, if you want to do without creating the table then it should be like below

```
Alter procedure test2 
As
Set NoCount ON
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tab') IS NOT NULL
Begin
    Drop table #temp
End

SELECT DeptID, DeptName INTO #tab from Department
Select * from #tab
Drop table #tab
```

Go